Not await an asynchronous method because it is like an endless loop - good practice?
I inherited a piece of software. This program is connected to an external hardware, which is a measurement device. Every 100 milliseconds, a value is read from this device and displayed to the user. When the user clicks a button, this continuous measurement is interrupted and no value will be displayed to the user anymore. Some action is done and when this action is finished, the program starts to take the measurement values again. In the code, this realized like this:
private ManualResetEventSlim _isPortReadyEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
private volatile bool _continueReadingValue;

private int _value;
public int Value
{
  get => _value;
  set
  {
      _value = value;
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
  }

}

private async Task StartValueReading()
{
    _isPortReadyEvent.Reset();
    _continueReadingValue = true;
    while (_continueReadingValue)
    {
         Value = await GetValueFromMeasurementDevice();
         // assigning the result to property Value displays the result on the GUI
         await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    _isPortReadyEvent.Set();
}

private async Task StopValueReading()
{
    _continueReadingValue = false;
    await Task.Run(_isPortReadyEvent.Wait);
}

At program start, StartValueReading is executed. When the button is clicked, the following method is executed:
private async Task ExecuteAction()
{
    await StopValueReading();
    await DoSomething();
    StartValueReading();

    DoSomeMoreWorkWhileValueIsReadAgain();
}

As described above, in the first line the reading of the value will be stopped. In the second line the action is performed. In the third line the program will start to read the value again. Note that the method is not awaited. This is necessary, because the method is more or less an endless loop. If the call was awaited, the last method would never be called.
The compiler shows a warning that StartValueReading() is not awaited. Although the program works really well in practice, this approach feels wrong to me. It looks like a misuse of async/await. Is this feeling correct? What problems could arise from this approach? Do you think it is necessary to refactor it, maybe to a completely different approach without async/await? (I know exception handling is a problem, but let's assume GetValueFromMeasurementDevice() will never throw an exception)

Your code is not complete. Value is not defined anywhere, nor does this explain how the stored value is used.

Secondly, to prevent needing to write an answer on hypotheticals: are you aware that asynchrony is not the same as parallelism? Because it seems like you're trying to achieve one by doing the other.

@Flater Assume that it is just a property. I am aware that asynchrony and parallelism are not the same, that's why I am asking the question.

If you understand this, then the question shouldn't be whether you should await this method, but whether it should be async in the first place, and how you actually intend to achieve your parallelism. That understanding is currently missing from the question.


It looks like a misuse of async/await.

It is.

Do you think it is necessary to refactor it, maybe to a completely different approach without async/await?

Yes.

Every 100 milliseconds, a value is read from this device

I'd just use a Timer. The API of your code and Timer are very similar in two regards:




Timer
your code




a switch to turn the thing on or off
Timer.Enabled
StartValueReading()/StopValueReading()


when the thing is doing something, its expected output is some event being raised
Timer.Elapsed
PropertyChanged



Compare this:
private async Task StartValueReading()
{
    _isPortReadyEvent.Reset();
    _continueReadingValue = true;
    while (_continueReadingValue)
    {
         Value = await GetValueFromMeasurementDevice();
         // assigning the result to property Value displays the result on the GUI
         await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    _isPortReadyEvent.Set();
}

to something like that:
private void StartValueReading()
{
    _measurementTimer.Enabled = true;
}



I inherited a piece software.

And it smells. Bad.
private volatile bool _continueReadingValue;

Do you (think you) know why this field is volatile? I'd follow Eric's advice "I leave the usage of "volatile" to real experts." ;) in a nutshell (SO answer summary) or in a watermelon (source blog post)
But you don't have to go to such low level.
What happens if Value is assigned the same value twice?
How many property changed events would you expect? How many do you get?
public int Value
{
  get => _value;
  set
  {
      _value = value;
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
  }
}

These indicate (to me) that previous authors of the code might not have had the time, experience, knowledge and/or mindset to write code that smells less. async/await was a somewhat advanced language feature when introduced, too advanced you might say for some developers.
Its usage is probably as sensible as the rest of the legacy code base you are dealing with.

I think you are awaiting the result somewhere: in StopValueReading. Except rather than doing so through the Task you have to define your own semaphore to keep track of it. You could eliminate _isPortReadyEvent by just awaiting the result of StartValueReading() in StopValueReading(), like this:
Task _valueReadingTask;

private async Task ExecuteAction()
{
    await StopValueReading();
    await DoSomething();
    _valueReadingTask = StartValueReading();

    DoSomeMoreWorkWhileValueIsReadAgain();
}

private async Task StopValueReading()
{
   _continueReadingValue = false;
   await _valueReadingTask;
}

You could also provide a cancellation token, which would potentially enable you to stop the task immediately without having to wait for the 100ms Wait to expire. However this causes the awaiter to throw an OperationCancelledException, which not everybody likes.

I took the freedom to demonstrate your good explanation in code, hope you are fine with it.

@DocBrown looks fine

Re cancellation, it depends on what the receiver of the token does with it.  It only throws if the receiver asks it to throw (though that will often be the most sensible thing to do so that you can unwind through a call stack without checking the cancellation state at every level).

Generally the code is ok. There's a slight risk that if you refactor StartValueReading to be say synchronous, then you end up blocking yourself. In particular ExecuteAction needs to be aware of the details of StartValueReading. This can be avoided by wrapping the call with say Task.Run().
But I don't think you will get rid of the warning either way. However warnings are just that: warnings. The compiler tries to tell you: are you sure this is not a mistake? Because most of the time you should await a task. But not always. Suppress it, move on.
There is a proper way of handling this. Create a background worker class, that manages the background task and implements say IAsyncDiposable that does the cleanup (including the final await). The cleanup can be called on application shutdown for example. That mitigates another risk of potential dangling background worker. But that's likely to be lots of work, not necessarily of any benefit. I would stick with YAGNI in this case.

I did not downvote this, but let me add a remark. It is very easy to get rid of the compiler warning. As soon as one writes Task task = StartValueReading(), the warning vanishes, I tried it out.

... the background worker solution, if I remember correctly, is an approach older than async/await in C#. It would work, but it is pretty clumsy in comparison with the more modern variants.

@DocBrown that's pretty much what I've meant by "suppress it". I typically do var _ = ...; which IMO has quite clear intent.

@DocBrown just because it's older and a bit clumsier doesn't mean it isn't better for some use cases. this would definitely be one of those, async/await patterns aren't really designed around this kind of infinitely running task, background worker are.

@bracco23 I'm not sure it exactly fits async / await (at least not at the level of awaiting the infinite task), but I think it fits just fine into the Task pattern.

@bracco23: if you say so. For me, the async/await solution described in the other answer looks straightforward and quite understandable. I have implemented background workers myself in the past, before async/await was available in C#, and they always required a lot more complicated, less clear code for achieving the same result.
